# If log in with SSO, the role will continue to be overwritten

Tags: wso2-api-manager

In WSO2 API Manager, we try to access Subscriber UI and Publisher UI through SSO. The SSO connection works fine, but Admin gave a special user the publisher creator permission. but If that user accesses the Subscriber UI again through SSO, the newly given permission(publisher creator) is lost and reset to the initial setting. What should I do in this case?

Comment: What is the APIM version you are using? Does that special user is assigned with the internal/publisher and internal/creator roles or have you assigned the permissions on creating and publishing APIs to that user? Share the roles assigned to the user. Are you using an external identity provider?

Comment: Check - https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/7203

Comment: we are using APIM 4.0.0.  i have assigned the permission on creating and pulishing APIs to that user.  but after reconnecting using SSO,  creating, pulishing permission gone.    And i did not use an wso2 identiy provider program.

Answer (score 2):

As per the description, I believe that you have created multiple Identity Providers to log in to Publisher and Devportal. Also, have enabled the Just-In-Time provisioning at the Identity Providers.

If yes, try adding the following configuration in the APIM's `deployment.toml` and try out the scenario

```
[authentication.framework.extensions]
provisioning_handler = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.provisioning.impl.SystemRolesRetainedProvisionHandler"
```

The default provisioning handler removes any additional roles that have been assigned to the logged-in user performing the sign-in process. The above-given Provisioning Handler is an extended version to not remove the additional (custom) assigned roles from the user using the login process.

Comment: Thanks @Athiththan,  I added this config a few days ago and it didn't work well then, but it works really well now. ha~~appriciate for your advise.

Comment: Saved lot of my time thank u so much. Hoping that it becomes the accepted answer.